# StrictMode policy violation (DiskReadViolation) overestimates result against measureTimeMillis{} block

Tags: android, android-strictmode

I have enabled StrictMode, and got a warning.

```
StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=509 ms: android.os.strictmode.DiskReadViolation
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1453)
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.checkAccess(UnixFileSystem.java:251)
        at java.io.File.exists(File.java:815)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.getDataDir(ContextImpl.java:2207)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.getFilesDir(ContextImpl.java:612)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getFilesDir(ContextWrapper.java:238)
```

But block `val ms = measureTimeMillis {...}` of problematic code gives me `14ms` execution duration.

It is a huge difference. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Most probably asynchronous operation

Comment: Making this operation asynchronous surely solve DiskReadViolation problem. But why measureTimeMillis {...} gives me 14ms instead of 509ms ?

Comment: I mean probably your disk operation is already asynchronous. So the control is returned to program when IO is still in progress